# Centos VPS OpenVZ Not rendering my updated codes with laravel5

Tags: centos, openvz

I'm having problem with my site it's not rendering updated pages on it. I attempt to clear the cache in server but I think it's not possible with OpenVZ VPS. I tried clearing the cache using laravel it didn't work either. What seems to be the solution to this?

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: yes I did but it's the same.